# how to reterieve all the images of a product using api?

Tags: magento2

need some sample code for the retrieving the images from magento. I always see the search results in php but not anything in java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Magento 2 REST API endpoint https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1GetListGet

Here's the example code for Java generated by PostMan

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("{{YOUR_STORE_ENDPOINT_HERE}}/rest/all/V1/products/Example/media/1")
  .get()
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("Authorization", "{{STORE_TOKEN_HERE}}")
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2")
  .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
  .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "ec0641a0-8200-473c-bc6a-ea11cd7e0175,f10e9cae-f952-4fd5-96a7-e1214c4be752")
  .addHeader("Host", "{{HOST_HERE}}")
  .addHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=qg603hoon7m8me6d7nne68t5ic")
  .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
  .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

You also need to generate admin user token for your user first which goes into `addHeader("Authorization", "{{STORE_TOKEN_HERE}}")`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://venia.test/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username={{ADMIN_LOGIN}}&password={{ADMIN_PASSWORD}}")
  .post(null)
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```